# Can you have too many product images on a product page?

Tags: image, consistency

We have an ability to make original high quality product images for most of our products. We're selling handheld radios which are used often so it's important to show people the design of a product. My current plan for images is:

3-4 images from all sides of a product.
2-3 close-up photos.
2-3 photos where the item is used in action.

I could probably add more. Would that be beneficial to the customer or just make one distracted?

Second very important point is that for some products we have no ability to take those pictures so we're relying on stock photos (some of them are average quality and are shot from 1 or 2 angles). So there is a consistency problem. Some products are very nurtured while others are slightly deprived. How would that affect customer behaviour?

Comment: why does a handheld radio needs 3-4 images? I would imagine 2 at most.....you can have 2 jpegs that when clicked they enlarge. Most people who buy them are usually people who use them frequently ( i.e. construction workers ) they buy them for specific reasons and features....listing those features in description is good enough, they do not care about the look of it so much as to click through 4 images. It is a utility item and showing 4 different angles of a radio may not be necessary. Such item better have a description of features.It is a utility item and not a fashion/tech item. IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as always with this type of question is: "It depends. You should test to find out".

#### Communicate Key Qualities

The obvious answer to your main question is yes, of course there can be too many images.  No one wants to click through 8 images of a measuring cup on a kitchenware site. Four to five would be more than enough, but 8 images of a house on a real estate website might not seem enough.

A reasonable approach might be ask "what's the minimum number of images that show all the key qualities of this product?"  Do you need 2-3 shots of that measuring cup in use? Probably not. One might do.

Consistency becomes not if the number of images on pages differ, but if some products effectively communicate the qualities of a product, and some do not. I see this on Amazon all the time. There's a large variety in the number and type of images, but I only ever notice anything when there's only one (or two very similar) image(s).

#### Test the Interaction

If I were in your shoes, I'd do some AB testing. Offer pages with different numbers of images, and use javascript event tracking to measure how much and how users are interacting with these product images. How much they click or cycle through images. On pages with low numbers of images, do users click looking for more? On pages with high numbers of images, do they make it to the end of the list?

These tests will give you page-specific insights. Do enough of them and you may create your own best practice for the number and type of images to display in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

**Make sure key information is highlighted**, and not too much information is presented to the user at once.  For example, the standard product page should probably only focus on a single image.

But as long as it is structured appropriately, **there is no downside to providing lots of information to the user.**  There is absolutely nothing wrong with providing 8-10 photos of products to potential buyers, and many people will find this helpful.  Good quality images are a real boon to e-commerce sites, since people cannot see the product in person before purchasing.

Also, I think you should **provide the photos where you have them** rather than focusing too much on the goal of "consistency".  Ideally, as a customer, I would like your site to be consistently good, with excellent photos for each product.  But if you don't have this, I would at least like to see good photos where they are available.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this depends heavily on the kind of product you are selling. I worked for different kinds of ecom companies - selling different products - and the key insight of testing this was: If the user needs to see a detail, it should be visible to him. If it is not, then it should be editorial - if it ain't that as well: Leave it out.

An example:

Shoes happen to have key features: Left side, right side (which might be different from the left side due to prints, etc), top and bottom. The top is maybe visible on the side pictures as well - so we can skip the top one. On top of that, we could add a video/editorial one. This makes it 4-5 pictures.

A circuit board for my computer might need a detail on the fan and on special details that differentiate the product from others (since nobody wants to see a thousand transistors)

For FURNITURE, that is a completely different story: Users want to see what is INSIDE the wardrobe, or maybe would like to see details how they can store things better. Then again, the amount of product picture would strongly vary based on the kind of furniture it is: A candle holder might not be needing as many pictures as a wardrobe that is holding different kind of clothing.

What I also learned: This is a very very very (did I say VERY?) important question you should, by any means, ask your customer: "What kind of details are important to you? What information do you need to purchase this item?"
Customer service will for sure gladly give you information on complaints / unanswered questions from customers. And, the handy side effect: It gives you a nice opportunity to start a cooperation with CS (which I found very valuable)!

So starting this, I would begin with asking myself (and a dozen co-employees): What is important to you when purchasing this product?

After 5 persons you will have a rough idea of what you should start with.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that still many shoppers aren't comfortable with buying something that they cannot touch and feel yet. at the best a product videos  give an idea of the product and also how it works.

It also depends on the type of product. For instance an automobile would have interior images of the product as well. If the product's usage is the selling point you should show images or videos of the product being used. if the product is a software, screen shots or videos of the application running would be needed.

So the while the answer is 'it depends' on the product it also means your product page needs to give as much images of the product as possible for the user to make a choice about buying it.